# webBrowser failure. Migration VB6 to VB.Net. ExecWB and QueryStatusMethod failure

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I want to migrate an application from VB6.0 to VB.net.
I migrate it myself and get an error on this two lines. The error says "ExecWB is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser"!!The same error with the ExecWB Method. I dont find any solution or any equivalent code in .net for that. Do I need an imprt or reference or equivalent type?

Please help.

```
eQuery = webBrowser.QueryStatusWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_COPY)
webBrowser.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PAGESETUP,   
SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, Nothing, Nothing)
```

webBrowser?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are two different `WebBrowser` things, the [`WebBrowser Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28VS.85%29.aspx) and the [`WebBrowser Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx). The *object* is the ActiveX version that you were using in VB6 while the *control* was completely redesigned to follow .Net standards. While there may be some common methods, properties and events between the two they are not really related.

You can continue to use the ActiveX version in .Net just fine if you want. You'll need to add a reference to it either via the Add References menu or by adding the `Microsoft Web Browser` object to your toolbox. If you want to use the .Net version then you'll need to find the updated way to do your specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

A [30s Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=ExecWB+.net+web+browser+control&meta=) returned [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/webbrowserzoom.aspx) that suggests you can use late binding on the ActiveXInstance property to access the methods directly.

Note that this method is marked as "infrastructure use only" and may well be subject to change/removal, etc at a later date.

Comment: And how can I add reference o fht e old VB6.0 Library? I have search on the reference menu but I dont find the equivalent Library..

Comment: You browse to wherever the OCX is on your system. Note that it was Chris that suggested it. The article I linked to showed you how to do it with the .NET one that you're already using.